# Export AWS Cognito Users with password

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Is it possible to export the AWS Cognito users with password from one pool and import them to another pool?

Possible way:

- I know we can ask users to reset the password but just wanted to know if is there any other way apart from this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is only one way to get this done is migration lambda trigger. In short:

1. create new cognito
2. create migration lambda
3. add this lambda as a trigger to login and/or forgotten passwords
4. point users at new cognito

upon login, Cognito will check locally and if user is not found, will use the trigger to check another cognito. If authentication is successful, old cognito will return object with all properties, incl passwords, which you can then insert into new cognito.

more info here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-migrate-user.html